# Sum of partial derivatives of a product over a symbolic number of variables

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I would like SymPy to evaluate an expression like the following:

[image: formula]

How would I define the symbols and the expression so that SymPy could handle it nicely? I would like to keep `N` as just a symbol, i.e. not make an actual finite list of `x`'s. I have tried various combinations of `IndexedBase` and `Sum` /`Product`, but didn't get it working right.

Comment: It is not difficult to compute that analytically. Why even use SymPy?

Comment: By the way, the desired result is twice the sum of the `x`'s.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The expression I gave would be part a larger one, which I cut out in the interest of keeping the question about SymPy, rather than my specific problem. I have done it all analytically, but I would like to make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally it would be this:

```
x = IndexedBase("x")
i, j, N = symbols("i j N")
expr = Sum(Product(exp(-x[j]**2), (j, 1, N)).diff(x[i]), (i, 1, N))
```

So far this is unevaluated, expr is

```
Sum(Derivative(Product(exp(-x[j]**2), (j, 1, N)), x[i]), (i, 1, N))
```

The method `doit` can be used to evaluate it. Unfortunately the differentiation of a product doesn't quite work yet: `expr.doit()` returns

```
N*Derivative(Product(exp(-x[j]**2), (j, 1, N)), x[i])
```

Rewriting the product as the sum prior to differentiation helps:

```
expr = Sum(Product(exp(-x[j]**2), (j, 1, N)).rewrite(Sum).diff(x[i]), (i, 1, N))
expr.doit()
```

returns

```
Sum(Piecewise((-2*exp(Sum(log(exp(-x[j]**2)), (j, 1, N)))*x[i], (1 <= i) & (i <= N)), (0, True)), (i, 1, N))
```

which is the correct result of differentiation. Sadly we have that extraneous condition in Piecewise, and also `log(exp(...))`  that should have been simplified. SymPy doesn't infer that `(1 <= i) & (i <= N)` is True from the context of the outer sum, and it also hesitates to simplify `log(exp` thinking `x[j]` might be complex. So I resort to surgical procedure with Piecewise, replacing it by the first piece, and to forcefully expanding logs:

```
e = expr.doit()
p = next(iter(e.atoms(Piecewise)))
e = expand_log(e.xreplace({p: p.args[0][0]}), force=True)
```

Now `e` is

```
Sum(-2*exp(Sum(-x[j]**2, (j, 1, N)))*x[i], (i, 1, N))
```

Couldn't get `exp(Sum(..))` to become a Product again, unfortunately.

Comment: Also, `factor(e)` recognizes that the double sum can be factored as a product of two sums.