# What exactly are indexed objects in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I don't understand what `indexed objects` in sympy are for. The documentation didn't help me understand the concept much.

For instance :

```
>>> from sympy import symbols, IndexedBase, Idx
>>> M = IndexedBase('M')
>>> i, j = symbols('i j', cls=Idx)
>>> M[i, j]
M[i, j]
```

What does this code do? What is `M[i,j]`?

All I understand is that an `indexed object` gives indices to individual sympy `symbols` .

I'm looking for a better explanation of `indexed objects` , along with it's relation to `IndexedBase` and `idx`

Comment: In this case you could think of `M` as a 2D array and `i, j` would be row/column indices into that array. Therefore the result of `M[i, j]` would be a single value

Comment: @CoryKramer I see. So when we create M, what are the initial values of the elements? Also, why do we create such an object? What is the point of doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One-line explanation: they represent a symbolic array of undetermined, possibly infinite, size.

Suppose you want to work with n symbols, how would you do that? Easy enough if n is a given number, like 10. But it's just n, an unspecified integer number. Formulas like that appear in mathematics all the time: "add or multiply (something) over the indices i=1, ..., n".

For example, suppose I have a function in n-dimensional space R<sup>n</sup>, such as f(x) = 1/distance(x, 0). The distance is, of course, the square root of the sum of squares of coordinates. And maybe I want to find some partial derivative of f. How to express all of this in SymPy? Like this:

```
from sympy import *
x = IndexedBase('x')
j, k, n = symbols('j k n', cls=Idx)
f = 1/sqrt(Sum(x[k]**2, (k, 1, n)))
print(f.diff(x[j]))
```

This computes the derivative of f with respect to the coordinate `x[j]`. The answer is

```
-Sum(2*KroneckerDelta(j, k)*x[k], (k, 1, n))/(2*Sum(x[k]**2, (k, 1, n))**(3/2))
```

which is correct (although perhaps the numerator could be simplified if we assume that j is in the range 1..n).

In the above example, `x[j]` is the coordinate with index j.  In your example, `M[i, j]` could be the entry of some matrix at position i, j.

- M is the name of symbolic array, its class is IndexedBase
- i and j are indices of that array, their class is Idx

The above are the classes that you would instantiate yourself. The class of M[i, j] is Indexed but you don't create those objects by using class name, `M[i, j]` simply does that.

Two recent questions with examples of working with indexed objects:

- [Create an unknown number of programmatically defined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372808/create-an-unknown-number-of-programmatically-defined-variables)
- [Sum of partial derivatives of a product over a symbolic number of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384322/sum-of-partial-derivatives-of-a-product-over-a-symbolic-number-of-variables)

Comment: Could you also explain what the difference is between setting `cls=Idx` and just setting `integer=True`? The latter also seems to work, only that it displays nicer in sums and products while the former displays an ugly Idx(i).

Answer (score 2):

Indexed is primarily used for two use-cases:

1. Formulas with symbolic subscripts. For example, `\sum_{i=1}^n a_i`. You could just use `Symbol('a_i')`, but them the `i` is not symbolic and in any way related to `Symbol('i')`. So for instance, `Sum(a_i, (i, 1, n))` will just give you `n*a_i`. Instead `IndexedBase('a')[i]` represents a different symbol for every value of `i`, and `Sum(IndexedBase('a')[i], (i, 1, n))` effectively represents the above summation.
2. N-d arrays. This is especially useful for code generation, because the SymPy code printers for languages like C or Fortran will print Indexed objects as array lookups automatically, for instance

   ```
   >>> a = IndexedBase('a')
   >>> i = Idx('i', (1, n))
   >>> ccode(a[i])
   'a[i]'
   >>> fcode(a[i])
   '      a(i)'
   ```

   This makes it very easy to write array-based code symbolically using SymPy and generate fast code that computes it.